# get tableView of a UISearchBar

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have an UISearchBar in on top of my TVC. If the search is active it displays another tableView on top of the normal tableView (this is normal). Now i need to get the "searchTableView" in prepareForSegue() because I need to call:

```
var newIndexPath = table.indexPathForSelectedRow!
```

and this fails if you search something.
I also can't do the decision in didSelectRowAtIndexPath() because the segue is called to fast because it is 'linked' directly to the UITableViewCell. I also tried to create the segue from the ViewController but this also fails because the segue needs to end on the same ViewController again.

So basically I want to ask if anyone knows how to solve the error in the Code line above will doing a search.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath;
    if (self.searchDisplayController.active) 
    {
        indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    } 
    else 
    {
        indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    }

    // Use the indexPath...
}
```

Comment: It isn't working because searchDisplayController was deprecated in iOS 8.0